# Solidity: What is this syntax with an external un-implemented function?

Tags: solidity

Newbie question!  I am trying to understand some Solidity code, and I see what is apparently the calling of an *unimplemented* function.  My question is about the syntax: `unimplFunc{value: x}(data)`.  What are the angle brackets for?

```
interface ICaller {
    struct CallDescription {
        uint256 value;
        bytes data;
    }

    function makeCall(CallDescription memory desc) external;
    function makeCalls(CallDescription[] memory desc) external payable;
}
```

Elsewhere, this unimplemented function is called like so:

```
function swap(
        ICaller caller,
        ICaller.CallDescription[] calldata calls
    )
        external
        payable
        whenNotPaused
        returns (uint256 returnAmount)
    {
       //
       // This is the syntax I am puzzled over
       //
       caller.makeCalls{value: 1}(calls);
        
        . . . etc . . .
```

Maybe that syntax is for over-riding a field in the struct argument?  What's especially puzzling is that this function `makeCalls` is never implemented.

If it helps, the input value I observed for `calls` is:

```
calls.value = 0
calls.data = 0xb3af37c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024000000000000000000000000eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee0000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000014000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002445636885000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee0000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f00000000000000000000000083314c5f8bab1f01a5f64e01cda3c4a0ea75b6ba00000000000000000000000083314c5f8bab1f01a5f64e01cda3c4a0ea75b6ba0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002789438280458ffd000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000002a1530c4c41db0b0b2bb646cb5eb1a67b715866700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011c37937e0800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064ad65d76d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005fd0169e00000000000000000000000083314c5f8bab1f01a5f64e01cda3c4a0ea75b6ba0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a new syntaxis introduced with [solc 0.7](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/070-breaking-changes.html#changes-to-the-syntax).

When making a call to a funciton you specify the ether amount to send and gas available to calle.

```
myContract.myFunction{gas: 3000000, value: 0.01 ether}(param1,...);
```

For solc version 0.6 the same line has to be written as

```
myContract.myFunction.gas(3000000).value(0.01 ether)(param1,...);
```

Comment: Thank you - can you explain what the significance of the `value` key?  I see that it's a member of the struct argument -- but is "value" have some special meaning (for instance, the value of the ether)?

Comment: @ThomasRuble You are correct `value` is the amount of ether you want to send with the function call. It is unrelated to `CallDescription` structure.